# Matrix multiplication order for multiple model transformations

Tags: mathematics, matrix, transformation

I have a problem in terms of what frame of reference, I should construct, scaling (S), rotation (R) and translation (T) for a model matrix (in that order). Let us assume the use of glm (or glsl), i.e. to mean column major representation.

I believe, it should be a matrix multiplication of:

```
M = T * R * S // S * R * T is what we want to apply, but due to being column major, the order gets reversed, due to (AB)^T =B^T*A^T
```

Now, if I have a previous transformation already applied (say M_prev), and I want to apply a transformation M on top of that, then is the correct form:

```
M_new = M_prev * M // M_new and M_prev are both column major. I'm post multiplying due to being column major, but this is incorrect, I guess?
```

I believe this is incorrect (at least in some experiments I carried out, please correct me if I'm wrong), and it should be the reverse. What is the flaw in my calculation of M_new?

Comment: Your two examples aren't consistent with one another. If `T*R*S` means T is being applied after R which is in turn applied after S, then `M_prev * M` means M_prev is being applied after M; or vice versa, assuming all of your matrices are constructed similarly. Are you expecting that somewhere in between the matrices are being transposed? You mention one set being column-major and another row-major, but it's not clear why your application would be mixing two different matrix conventions.

Comment: All matrices that I'm using are column major. Nothing is row major. I'm trying to understand why the 2nd equation is wrong. I added a comment to further clarify. I'm trying to applying S, then R and then T. But, reversing that order due to column major.

Comment: I further added more. Nothing is row major. Everything is column major. Maybe, I'm doing the 2nd part correct for a 'row major' matrix, but that's what I'm trying to understand. Why is this wrong for column major?

Comment: If the column major order for TRS is "later * earlier" then why would you expect that for M_prev and M it would become "earlier * later"? ie. T is supposed to happen after R, so you put it on the left. M is supposed to happen after M_prev, so why do you put it on the right? If you're using the same matrix convention throughout then your order of multiplication should not change. Where has our reasoning diverged?

Comment: That thinking makes sense. So, it seems I blindly applied the post vs pre multiplication (without understanding it correctly), without thinking about it in a more intuitive sense of earlier vs later.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer. Maybe, talk a little about pre vs post multiplication, so that it can help someone like me who is utterly confused.

Comment: I'll confess I still don't understand what the question or confusion was in the first place, so I'm not sure what needs to be explained in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking into account that matrices are column-major as you said, then yes, 
it is incorrect.

so,

`M_new = M_prev * M` would apply first matrix `M` then `M_prev` which is not want what you want - think of them as some transformation matrices, like `S`, `T`, `R` and nothing more ...

Therefore if you want `M` be applied after 'M_prev' just do

`M_new = M * M_prev`